# Assassins in zero-dimensional local rings

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, nonnoetherian

During a study of the behaviour of assassins and torsion functors (cf. [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s40306-017-0233-0)), I met the following problem about assassins in $0$-dimensional local rings.

Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and let $\mathfrak{a}\subseteq R$ be a nil ideal (i.e., an ideal consisting only of nilpotent elements). We consider the following statements:

(1) $\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M/\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M))=0$ for every $R$-module $M$;

(2) ${\rm Ass}_R(M/\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M))=\emptyset$ for every $R$-module $M$.

(Clearly, in both statements it suffices to consider only monogeneous $R$-modules $M$.)

Here, $\Gamma_{\mathfrak{a}}(M)=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}(0:_M\mathfrak{a}^n)$ denotes the $\mathfrak{a}$-torsion submodule of $M$, and ${\rm Ass}_R(N)$ denotes the assassin of an $R$-module $N$, i.e., the set of prime ideals of $R$ of the form $(0:_Rx)$ for some $x\in N$.

One can show that (1) implies (2). A bunch of examples I checked indicates that also the converse might hold, at least if $\mathfrak{a}$ is the maximal ideal in a $0$-dimensional local ring. So:

> Does (2) imply (1) if $\mathfrak{a}$ is the maximal ideal in a $0$-dimensional local ring?